# Python plotting multidimensional list?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list that all of the elements are list themselves, usually having only one element, but some have two elements, or none.

eg.

`list=[[1],[2],[4,-1],[5],[ ]]`

(they are x-coordinates solutions between a variable line and a variable 3D surface for each time. I wanted to use numpy array for efficiency but didn't know how to use it in circumstances like this-variable dimensions)

and another correponding list

`time=[1,2,3,4,5]`

(actual length of data is ~100000)

I'd like to draw the values of list versus time.
The problem is, obviously, that dimensions are different between two lists. So, conceptually, I'd like to draw just for one elements for each time, but Python rejects even that, because there're some elements which is [ ].

So basically I'm stuck on one-element case, and if somebody suggests a way to treat multiple elements case (like [4,-1] above) it would be appreciated. (I found solutions using sympy.solvers.solve and sympy.nsolve so I guess the solutions are ordered in random order. So I think I should find which solution(element) is closer to previous solution -like we can guess that 4 is the original solution changing and -1 is additional solution- and distinguish them.)

Comment: What behavior do you desire for the `[]`, `[a]`, and `[a,b]` cases

Comment: @RushabhMehta I'd like to plot a vs time, ignoring [ ] (no solution cases) and when there are two solutions, I'd like to overplot b vs time on the plot also. (As I've wrote above I admit that distinguishing which is a and which is b would be not so easy.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a stacked bar plot to represent the data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
l = [[1],[2],[4,-1],[5],[]]
a, b = zip(*[i+[0, 0][:abs(len(i)-2)] for i in l]) 
time=[1,2,3,4,5]
plt.bar(list(range(len(l))), a, 0.5, color='#d62728', yerr=time, label='variable line')
plt.bar(list(range(len(l))), b, 0.5, bottom=a, yerr=time, label='3D surface')
plt.ylabel('coordinates')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]